# Do people still play Battlefield 1942?

Tags: battlefield-1942

I was wondering if people still play this awesome multiplayer game or not? I was thinking to get back to after many years gap but heard somewhere that it has lost online servers, after gamespy shut down its support for battlefield 1942. Are there still any servers up?

Comment: Not an answer, but I daresay there are _some_ (likely very few). https://www.gametracker.com/search/bf1942/AU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Since the initial release though, some problems appeared, and were solved with fixes. As [this post on EA Answers](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-1942/How-to-Play-Battlefield-1942-Online-Today-Where-to-Download-for/td-p/4550403) states, there are some patches that need to be applied in order to play the game (all needed info is on that link).

If you seek a general list of all available servers, you can use this search on Game Tracker :

[BF 1942 servers](https://www.gametracker.com/search/bf1942/?).